# Get linked work items test findings in an Azure pipeline build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

In an Azure pipeline run, work items can be related to failed tests.
How can the work items related to a failed test be retrieved via de [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)?

[image: pipeline results example]

My goal is to validate all test findings (test fails) have a work item *(in our case of type 'user story')* linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the following:

1. [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1). Here you can find needed runs.
2. [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1). Use Run Id to get results. New bugs you can find in the `associatedBugs` property.

Comment: Thanks. I found these calls, but I overlooked I needed `Test Management` rights on the PAT.

Comment: The `associatedBugs` property only lists work items of type `bug`. In the pipeline other types are supported/displayed. Do you have any idea on how to retrieve those?

Comment: @R.Oosterholt can you check `workItems` of `ResultDetails` property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#resultdetails

Comment: I'm using `workitems` and, however the name suggests it returns all workitems, it only returns linked bugs...